# Equivalent of $(this) in native javascript

Tags: jquery, native, traversal

I wanted to add and event listener to a button and I am still relatively new on coding purely on javascript, so I don't know what are the native equivalent of `$this`

in my code

```
// the markup

<ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#" data-something="value">text</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-something="value2">text2</a></li>
</ul>

var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
menu.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // console.log $(this).val
    // what I wanted is to get that data-attribute of the clicked item
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the event handler `this` will represent the element to which the event handler is bound.  You will not have all of the utility functions provided by jQuery.  So in your example you will not be able to retrieve the data attribute by using `this.data("something")`

To retrieve the value of the custom attribute the code must pass the event to the function.  From the `event` or `e` in the example, the `target` property will contain the element that triggered the event, which may not always be the element to which the event handler was bound, due to the propagation of events.  Use the `getAttribute` method to retrieve the value of custom attribute.  Also refrain from making the custom attributes upper case as the html specifications do not allow for this and will create inaccessible attributes.

```
var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
menu.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    alert(e.target.getAttribute("data-something"));
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pjcvB/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below code to get an **almost** equivalent of `$(this)`

```
document.querySelector("#myId").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(this);    //Prints the Element
  $this = new Array(e.target);
  console.log($this);   //Prints the Object
});
```

[PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/RQLydg)

Hope this helps.