# jQuery $(this), .onclick function and native javascript for custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small bit of jQuery code and I'm trying to understand how to convert it to vanilla JS and also make it reusable on multiple elements.

I read [Equivalent of $(this) in native javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579066/equivalent-of-this-in-native-javascript) and I really have no clue where to begin. Can someone help me out by any chance?

**jQuery code:**

```
$(".icon").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.cap').addClass('active');
  $(this).one(transitionEvent, function(event) {
    // Do something here
    $('.cap').removeClass('active')
  });
});
```

**which is specific for this HTML code:**

```
        <div class="icon">
          <i></i>
          <span class="cap"></span>
        </div>
```

I understand I have to do the following in this specific order:

```
// 1 find the .icon and bind the .click (done) 
// 2 toggle active the .icon (done) 
// 3 add class .active to the .cap class  
// 4 convert .one into JS equivalent 
// 5 now remove the .active from the .cap class
```

**JS work in progress:**

```
    // 1 find the .icon and bind the .click
var myfunct = document.querySelector(".icon");
myfunct.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // 2 toggle active the .icon
    el.classList.toggle('active')
        // now how can I proceed? for #3 in my list?
});
```

Comment: So start with binding click handlers to all the icons. Once you figure that out, than you set the class....

Comment: I did and that seems to be simple to understand, but the rest for example to convert the $(this) I have no clue what to do? Can you help?

Comment: `this` is the object... so do not wrap it and you get the DOM element.....

Comment: Is there a reason you need to bind a `.one` handler at every click instead of just keeping it bound for each icon? And did you mean `transitionEnd`?

Comment: ok that seems clear too, what about the .one function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at this page http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

There are bunch of examples of how to rewrite specific parts of jQuery code to vanilla JS.

Some examples for your code snippet:

`$(".icon")` => `document.querySelectorAll('.icon')`

`$(this).toggleClass('active');` => `el.classList.toggle('active')`

Here is how you can bind `click` event to all `.icon` elements:

```
var icons = document.querySelectorAll('.icon');

icons.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        el.classList.toggle('active');
        // ...
    })
})
```

`$.one` is just one time binding, its equal to bind with `addEventListener` and inside the listener you call `removeEventListener` to remove it (so it can not be called second time).

```
var handler = function () {
    // Do something here

    el.removeEventListener(eventName, handler); // here we remove the handler
};
el.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
```

So together it will be something like this:

```
var icons = document.querySelectorAll('.icon');

icons.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        el.classList.toggle('active');
        var cap = el.querySelector('.cap');
        cap.classList.add('active');

        var handler = function () {
            // Do something here
            cap.classList.remove('active');
            el.removeEventListener(transitionEvent, handler);
        };
        el.addEventListener(transitionEvent, handler);
    })
});
```

Comment: `$.one` is just one time binding, its equal to bind with `addEventListener` and inside the listener you call `removeEventListener` to remove it (so it can not be called second time).

Comment: I added example on how to convert $.one

Comment: Here you go. You just need to move the declaration of `cap` variable to the `click` handler, and look for the element on the `el` element rather than on `document`.

Comment: amazing learning out of this! Thanks for the detailed explanation at each point.